# Exporting landcover clasiffication from ENVI to SAGA

Tags: saga, envi

I have basic knowledge in remote sensing and GIS. I have generated landcover map in ENVI 4.7. How can I transfer or Export/Import this into SAGA so that I perform other functions in SAGA. I want to generate the factor (R*K*LS*C*P)in RUSLE (soil loss modelling) using SAGA.

Answer (score 0):

SAGA can handle `ENVI .hdr labelled raster` format through GDAL.

Just drag and drop the data to SAGA GUI window. If preferred, activating `Tool Libraries | Import/Export | GDAL/OGR | Import Raster` will do the same.

(At the time this question was posted, SAGA version was probably 2.1.1 or 2.1.2. So I think this answer is/was valid).

Comment: Is your answer valid for the new version of SAGA 9.0.1?